# Asymptotic bound of the number of possible grouping of $n$ objects

Tags: combinatorics

I'm working on estimating the error probability of some Maximum Likelihood Estimator, where the problem boils down to obtaining upper and lower bounds of a combinatorial number described below.

Suppose I have $n$ distinct balls, and I want to assign them into $k$ disjoint groups. Each ball has to be assigned to exactly one group, and each group must contain at least one ball. Denote the number of all possible such assignments by $S(n, k)$. Is there any existing results about the asymptotic behavior of $S(n, k)$ as $n$ tends to infinity while $k$ remains fixed?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Asymptotic_approximation

Comment: Thanks @MikeEarnest. That's exactly what I'm looking for!